# Shipping Personal Items from Canada to the US

Tags: usa, shipping

I initially studied in Canada and will now be shipping my stuff (mainly my clothes) to New York to continue my studies (as a student). I was told that I would have to complete [the CBP 3299 form](http://forms.cbp.gov/pdf/CBP_Form_3299.pdf) . I have a few questions I hope you can answer:

1. Under section II, question 10, I selected A(1) and C(1). My question is: Where do I list the personal effects (the clothing) on the form? I could put it under part D of section IV, but under that section, there is no mention of personal effects for non-residents in A, B or C. To make this question possibly clearer for you to understand, under part IV, I selected B(8), meaning that on the next page, I should only list items which pertain to B(8), i.e. household effects. So as I said earlier, where would I list "clothing"?
2. My second question pertains to the value given for each item I state. If I do list clothing (which are my used clothes and not for sale), what value should I put? The total value of the clothing may be around $300 but I'm not sure if customs sees this, then I would have to pay duties on my clothing. May I please have your suggestions?

Comment: For clothes that you own more than 1 year you no need to pay duties. In the part D you should make a list of your personal stuff. I assume, that price of each item can be choosed approximately.

Comment: Clothing is definetly a "household effects" thing if you not going to present it somebody or sell it

Comment: This question is about long-term residence, and would be better on the Expatriates site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NewStudent: I have done shipping in the past from Canada as a student to USA and I was coming as a student. And you do not have to pay any duty of import on your are coming as a student and you are bringing used stuff to the country.

I have highlighted details you can fill and get it verified before you hand it over to the authority.

As you are just bringing your personal belongings you should not be paying any import fees or duty.

Good Luck

[image]